# function influence on already running function JavaScript

Tags: javascript

So i have a function that show me random number images from the CSS class.
The problem is when I am running the application twice , the second application change the images on the first application, while the random numbers DONT show up in the second application.
I thought it could be because i didn't have local variable, but i get the same problem with or without the global vars. I could use Iframes, but there must be a away to get it work Js Only ?

I created a jsFiddle that show the problem, just press the run button twice and play with the dices you'll see my problem.
http://jsfiddle.net/dymond/gUL9U/

and the function that creates the classes.

```
function dicesides_func(nr){
    // go to dice-window-wrapper again
    // this could be put in a seporate functon
    var elementToAddDice=" dice-window-wrapper ",
    obj=this, // using this here that's why it's called wiht
    dice,i=0,total=0; // all the dice in this dice window
    // dicesides_func.call to set the right this context
    if(nr)
    {
        while((" "+obj.className+" ").indexOf(elementToAddDice)==-1){
            obj=obj.parentNode;
        }
        obj=obj.getElementsByTagName("ul")[2];
        var dicessides = createElementWithClass('li',nr);
        obj.appendChild(dicessides);
        // calculate total (can do in a seporate function)

        dice = obj.getElementsByTagName("li");
    }
    else
    {
        dice = document.getElementsByClassName("dice");   
    }
    for(i=0;i<dice.length;i++){
        total=total+getNumberForClass(dice[i].className);
    }
    //alert(total);

    var wrapper = document.getElementsByClassName("dice-toolbar-counter-wrapper")[0];

    while (wrapper.hasChildNodes()) {
        wrapper.removeChild(wrapper.lastChild);
    }

    var ttl = total.toString();
    var arr = [];
    for (var i = 0;i<ttl.length;i++) {
        var digit = ttl[i];
        var newelem = createElementWithClass('li',"side-" + ttl[i]);
        //alert(dice_toolbar_counter_wrapper_Li)
        wrapper.appendChild(newelem);
    } 

}
```

Comment: The problem is the very same as in your previous question [Prevent overwrite running function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14844200/prevent-overwrite-running-function)

Comment: @Bergi With the local and global variables ? I actually tried that first, but still problem :/