# Application that get the Sum from previously running application

Tags: javascript

I have a dice function that multiply the sum of the dices, stores the sum in a variable, and print the sum out. No problem, but when i run the application twice. The second application influence the sum of the first one.

I tried with the localStorage, but nothing worked. This is the closest i have come to show different results in the two application

I want to be able to have multiply application running but not leaking information.
Any tips ?

A jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/dymond/gUL9U/ <-- run the application twice and you see the problem.

```
function dicesides_func(nr){
    // go to dice-window-wrapper again
    // this could be put in a seporate functon
    var elementToAddDice=" dice-window-wrapper ",
    obj=this, // using this here that's why it's called wiht
    dice,i=0,total=0; // all the dice in this dice window
    // dicesides_func.call to set the right this context
    if(nr)
    {
        while((" "+obj.className+" ").indexOf(elementToAddDice)==-1){
            obj=obj.parentNode;
        }
        obj=obj.getElementsByTagName("ul")[2];
        var dicessides = createElementWithClass('li',nr);
        obj.appendChild(dicessides);
        // calculate total (can do in a seporate function)

        dice = obj.getElementsByTagName("li");
    }
    else
    {
        dice = document.getElementsByClassName("dice");   
    }
    for(i=0;i<dice.length;i++){
        total=total+getNumberForClass(dice[i].className);
    }
    //alert(total);

    var wrapper = document.getElementsByClassName("dice-toolbar-counter-wrapper")[0];

    while (wrapper.hasChildNodes()) {
        wrapper.removeChild(wrapper.lastChild);
    }

    var ttl = total.toString();
    var arr = [];
    for (var i = 0;i<ttl.length;i++) {
        var digit = ttl[i];
        var newelem = createElementWithClass('li',"side-" + ttl[i]);
        //alert(dice_toolbar_counter_wrapper_Li)
        wrapper.appendChild(newelem);
    } 

}
```

Comment: Can u post small code with error in it?

Comment: @bighostkim How do you mean ?
I wont get any errors when I am debugging it.

Comment: I would detect where the problem is, then ask how to overcome that problem. Unless I was very bored, I wouldn't go through all your code. Someone may though.

Comment: Exact duplicate of [function influence on already running function JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14852647/1048572). Please delete this one; if you had news you should [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/14852647/edit) the question

Comment: @bighostkim No worry. I been stuck with this problem for a while now anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code:
Main.js

```
function pageWrap(){
    /* --------DIV TAGGAR MED CLASS -------- */

    var outerDiv = createElementWithClass('div', 'dice-window-wrapper'),
    innerDiv = createElementWithClass('div', 'dice-menubar-wrapper');
    outerDiv.appendChild(innerDiv);
    document.getElementById("page-content-wrapper").appendChild(outerDiv);


    var dice_windows_wrapper_close = createElementWithClass('div', 'close');
    innerDiv.appendChild(dice_windows_wrapper_close);

    var dice_toolbar_wrapper_close = createElementWithClass('div', 'dice-toolbar-wrapper');
    outerDiv.appendChild(dice_toolbar_wrapper_close);

    var add_remove_roll = createElementWithOutClass('ul');
    dice_toolbar_wrapper_close.appendChild(add_remove_roll);

    var dice_content_wrapper = createElementWithClass('div', 'dice-content-wrapper');
    outerDiv.appendChild(dice_content_wrapper);

    var dice_toolbar_counter_wrapper_Ul = createElementWithClass('ul', 'dice-toolbar-counter-wrapper');
    dice_toolbar_wrapper_close.appendChild(dice_toolbar_counter_wrapper_Ul);

    add_remove_roll_func("add","remove","roll");

    var lielement = createElementWithOutClass('li');
    add_remove_roll.appendChild(lielement);

    lielement.appendChild(dice_toolbar_counter_wrapper_Ul);

    /* <div class="dice-content-wrapper">*/  /*Visar tärningen som kastast*/
    var ul_dice_sides = createElementWithOutClass('ul');
    dice_content_wrapper.appendChild(ul_dice_sides);

    /*###CREATE ADD_REMOVE_ROLL DICES ###*/
    function add_remove_roll_func(){
        for (var i = 0; i<arguments.length; i++){
            li_dice_side_one = createElementWithClass('li',arguments[i]);
            add_remove_roll.appendChild(li_dice_side_one);

        }
    }

    /*ADD EVENT*/
    function AddEvent(){ 
        var AddEvent = "add"; 
        var addClass= document.getElementsByClassName(AddEvent); 
        addClass=addClass[addClass.length-1]; 
        addClass.addEventListener("click", addDiceEvent, true); 
        var diceArray = Array=[ 
        "dice dice-side-one", 
        "dice dice-side-two", 
        "dice dice-side-three", 
        "dice dice-side-four", 
        "dice dice-side-five", 
        "dice dice-side-six"]; 
        function addDiceEvent() { 
            var rand = diceArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * diceArray.length)];
            dicesides_func.call(addClass,rand);
           document.getElementById('mySound').play();
         }
    }
    AddEvent(); 
    /*ADD EVENT END*/               
    /*REMOVE DICE*/
    function RemoveEventDice(){ 
        var removeEvent = "remove"; 
        var removeClass= document.getElementsByClassName(removeEvent); 
        var remove=removeClass[removeClass.length-1]; 
        remove.addEventListener("click", removeDice, true); 

        function removeDice(e) { 
            var obj=e.target; 
            var elementToRemove=" dice-window-wrapper "; 
            while((" "+obj.className+" ").indexOf(elementToRemove)==-1){ 
                obj=obj.parentNode; 
            } 
            var allDiceInWindow=obj.getElementsByClassName("dice"); 
            var diceToRemove=allDiceInWindow[allDiceInWindow.length-1]; 
            diceToRemove.parentNode.removeChild(diceToRemove); 
            dicesides_func.call(remove);//dicesides_func();
        }

    }
    RemoveEventDice();
    /*REMOVE DICE END*/
    /*ROLL DICE*/
    function rollEvent(){ 
        var rollDices = "roll"; 
        var addClass= document.getElementsByClassName(rollDices); 
        addClass=addClass[addClass.length-1]; 
        addClass.addEventListener("click", rollDice, true); 
        var diceArray = Array=[ 
        "dice dice-side-one", 
        "dice dice-side-two", 
        "dice dice-side-three", 
        "dice dice-side-four", 
        "dice dice-side-five", 
        "dice dice-side-six"]; 
        function rollDice(e) { 
            var obj=e.target; 
            var elementToRemove = " dice-window-wrapper "; 
            while((" "+obj.className+" ").indexOf(elementToRemove)==-1){ 
                obj=obj.parentNode; 
            }
            var allDiceInWindow=obj.getElementsByClassName("dice"); 
            for(var i = 0; i<allDiceInWindow.length; i++){
                // set the name individually for each die
                var name = diceArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * diceArray.length)]; 
                allDiceInWindow[i].className = name;
            }
            dicesides_func.call(addClass);//dicesides_func();
        }   
    }
    rollEvent();
    /*END ROLL DICE*/

    function CloseEvent(){  /*BehÃ¶ver Ã¤ndras om index sidan Ã¤ndras*/
        var CloseEvent = "close"; 
        var addClassArr= document.getElementsByClassName(CloseEvent); 
        var addClass = addClassArr[addClassArr.length-1]; 
        addClass.addEventListener("click", closebutton, true); 
        function closebutton(e) { 
            var classToRemove = " "+"dice-window-wrapper"+" "; 
            var obj=e.target; 
            while((" "+obj.className+" ").indexOf(classToRemove)==-1){ 
                obj=obj.parentNode; 
            }        
            obj.parentNode.removeChild(obj); 
        }
    }

    CloseEvent();    
    movewrap();
}
```

functioner.js

```
/*###CREATE ELEMENT WITH CLASS ###*/

function createElementWithClass(elementName, className)
{
    var el = document.createElement(elementName);
    el.className = className;
    return el;
}

/*###CREATE ELEMENT WITHOUT CLASS ###*/
function createElementWithOutClass(elementName)
{
    var el = document.createElement(elementName);
    return el;
}
/*###CREATE ELEMENT WITH ID ###*/
function createElementWithId(elementName, idName)
{
    var element = document.createElement(elementName);
    element.id = idName;
    return element;
}    

/* Funktionen som visar nya tabort och kasta tÃ¤rningarna ## END */

function getNumberForClass(className){
    var diceArray = Array=[ 
    "dice dice-side-one", 
    "dice dice-side-two", 
    "dice dice-side-three", 
    "dice dice-side-four", 
    "dice dice-side-five", 
    "dice dice-side-six"]; 
    return diceArray.indexOf(className)+1;
}

function dicesides_func(nr){
    var elementToAddDice=" dice-window-wrapper ", obj=this, dice,i=0,total=0;
        while((" "+obj.className+" ").indexOf(elementToAddDice)==-1){
            obj=obj.parentNode;
        }
        obj=obj.getElementsByTagName("ul")[2];
    if(nr){
        var dicessides = createElementWithClass('li',nr);
        obj.appendChild(dicessides);
        dice = obj.getElementsByTagName("li");
    }else{   
        dice = obj.getElementsByTagName("li");
    }

    for(i=0;i<dice.length;i++){
        total=total+getNumberForClass(dice[i].className);
    }

 //   console.log(obj.parentNode.parentNode.className.getElmentsByClassName[]);

    var wrapper = obj.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByClassName("dice-toolbar-counter-wrapper")[0];
    while (wrapper.hasChildNodes()) {
        wrapper.removeChild(wrapper.lastChild);
    }
    var ttl = total.toString();
    for (var x = 0;x<ttl.length;x++) {
        var newelem = createElementWithClass('li',"side-" + ttl[x]);
        //alert(dice_toolbar_counter_wrapper_Li)
        wrapper.appendChild(newelem);
    } 
}
```

Comment: well look at me not following my own suggestions ^^, i would rather use getElementById() and setting different IDs for the different wrappers but this seems to work.

Comment: So basicly what i did was changing the call from 
dicesides_func(); to  dicesides_func.call(addClass); because then the variable "nr" returned an element. Then i used  obj.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByClassName("dice-toolbar-counter-wrapper")[0]; to retrive the correct count wrapper and used that one instead of the first one in document.

Answer (score 0):

Select the proper wrapper and you should be fine: perhaps use a global counter variable when you create the application to know later on which application you are currently using?

This section selects the first wrapper:

```
var wrapper = document.getElementsByClassName("dice-toolbar-counter-wrapper")[0];
```

if i change this 0 to a 1 instead i mess upp application no 2 instead of 1, because you are actually selecting the [0] key in the array of wrappers.

*Snyggt btw!*

Comment: @lesus Sonesson. Tack:), But I could maybe use an for loop to catch al the classes ? Dont really know how to connect it to the var wrap thoug

Comment: Realized there's more to it, you are using the getElementsByClassName quite frequent.

Note that the remove and rollEvent does not work properly when you have multiple instances this is because they count all dices created

You would need to pass a variable to dicesides_func() which indicates which instance of the application you are communicating with

Comment: Actually the remove and roll event are not connected, since I didn't need them to show the problem. Sorry if I'm slow now, but how do you mean match to the wrapper key. I get that if i change the index from 0 to 1, it move the sum to window 2.. But as you know now. Don't how to make it independent to the window

Comment: No but they behave diffrently then add, somehow the addDice knows which instance of the application it is being used in

The key of the array is what you put inside the brackets in this case [0], so if you could do [ID] instead of [0] you would adress the correct instance of the application, if you have the ID variable set to the correct number that is.